# Excution flow issue in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

here in this I am making call to provider (http call),its getting called successfully but
I am getting execution flow problem .I want output as

```
4.3274
hi

but its printing

hi 
4.3274

<ion-buttons end>
                <button ion-button (click)="showcalculation()">Calculate</button>
            </ion-buttons>

             showcalculation(){    
                this.quoteServe.calSunShine().subscribe(data=>{     
                  console.log(data);
                })
                console.log("hi");   
              }

         **provider method:**

         calSunShine(){
            const body=new URLSearchParams();
            const header= new Headers();[enter image description here][1]   
            header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            return this.http.post(this.base_url+"restInsertQuote/getsunshine",  body.toString(),{headers : header}).map(response => response.json()); 
          }


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHyQ3.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run everything inside of the `subscribe` function *after* because `subscribe` is *async* and the rest of the code will run *sync*.

If you really want to change that flow just change the code to be called inside of the `subscribe`, like:

```
 //Somewhere in your class
 let sunshine: any;

 showcalculation(){    
    this.quoteServe.calSunShine().subscribe(data=>{     
       //run this before
       console.log("hi");  
       //then
       console.log(data);

       // Extended example
       this.sunshine = data;
       // Let's use sunshine for something
       // This will run after and will print server data.
       this.doSomethingWithSunshine();
    });
    //This will run first and will print undefined.
    this.doSomethingWithSunshine();
 }

 doSomethingWithSunshine(): void {
     console.log(this.sunshine);
 }
```

Comment: Or use promises

Comment: You will be able to use that value (`this.sunshine`) after you set that value inside of the `subscribe`, I will extend my answer to cover that case. If this answer solves your question remember to set it as the solution.